# ExtJS 3.0.0 autoreload json store

Tags: json, extjs3

I need to reload my chart's json store automatically on interval of 2 minutes.

**This is my code:**

```
tab = new Ext.Panel({
    id: "id-" + node.id,
    closable: true,
    title: node.attributes.text,
    layoutConfig: {
        columns: 3
    },
    defaults: {
        frame: true,
        height: 230,
        border: true
    },
    items: [
        new Ext.chart.LineChart({
            store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                url: 'dashboard/CantServicios',
                root: 'cantservicio',
                autoLoad: true,
                ields: ['NOMBRE_SERVICIO', 'CANT']
            }),
            xField: 'NOMBRE_SERVICIO',
            yField: 'CANT',
            width: 840
        })
    ]
});
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Ext.util.TaskRunner

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/?mobile=/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner

So if you look at the sample in the docs link above you should see that you can easily define a function that just performs a load on your store and then it's just a matter of using that in as the run config option.